# Creating a file with a list of paths (nested directories)

Tags: bash, echo, cat

I have a set of nested directories in a tree-like structure, and every directory at the bottom of the tree contains another directory called "dump".

I would like to create a file called "paths" with the all the paths to the "dump" directories, each one separated by a new line.

My attempt is:

```
echo ./*/*/*/dump | cat >paths
```

This kind of works, but the paths are not separated by a new line. How can I achieve this, possibly using echo and cat?

Comment: am I the only one, that didn't get you? you want to create the file `/.../.../.../.../dump`? or you want to create the file contains those paths? Where is the source input of those `/..../../dump` lines?

Comment: @Kent I want to create the file containing those paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find` instead:

```
find . -type d -path '*/dump' > paths
```

or else just replace `echo` by `printf` in your `glob`:

```
printf "%s\n" ./*/*/*/dump >paths
```

Comment: I like the one with printf, seems like the simplest and most elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using `echo` with the glob and pipe it to `xargs` one line at a time(`-n1`) and write it to the file as

```
echo ./*/*/*/dump | xargs -n1 > file
```

Comment: @jm666: yup it will I guess, `xargs` can read by null separated values, by I can't make it pipe to `xargs` that way. Do you have a suggestion or it can't be done?